# Spring Integration IP UDP - IN/OUTBOUND Error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am trying to make communication between 2 application :

In 1st app I have do something like this and working without no error, it's working or not that i don't no.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/new_tutorial.xml");
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

XML configuration for it :

```
    <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" expression="''">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="60000" />
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="quakeinfo.channel">
        <int:queue capacity="10"/>
    </int:channel>

    <int:channel id="quakeinfotrigger.channel" />

    <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" expression="''">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="60000" />
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-ip:udp-outbound-channel-adapter id="metoo" channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" port="11111" host="localhost"/>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="messageLogger" log-full-message="true" channel="quakeinfo.channel" level="ERROR">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="5000" />
    </int:logging-channel-adapter>
```

In second application I am doing like this :

```
public class InboundESB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/getinbound.xml");       
    }
}
```

in xml code of second application :

```
    <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" expression="''">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="60000" />
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="quakeinfotrigger.channel" />

    <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" expression="''">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="60000" />
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-ip:udp-inbound-channel-adapter id="metoo" port="11111" channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel"/>
```

when I execute second application after first one it's give me an error :

```
org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler handleMessageInternal
SEVERE: org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel quakeinfotrigger.channel.
```

I want to pass message from onr application to other application but I am new to spring integration so i don't know that how to do so ? 
So any help on it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following.
Your receiver app:

```
<int:channel id="quakeinfotrigger.channel">
        <int:queue />
    </int:channel>

    <int-ip:udp-inbound-channel-adapter id="metoo" port="11111" channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel"
        output-channel="logger"
        ref="echoService" 
        method="test">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
    </int:service-activator>

    <bean id="echoService"
        class="com.foo.bar.EchoService" />

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" logger-name="com.foo.bar"/>


public class EchoService {
    public String test(String input) {
        return input + ":echo";
    }
}

public class InboundESB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/getinbound.xml");
context.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

The message comes via inbound channel and when it's being received the method `test` from `echoService` is called. The reply is send to `logger` channel that prints it on the console.

Your sender app:

```
<int:channel id="quakeinfotrigger.channel" />

    <int:gateway id="sender"
        service-interface="com.foo.bar.Sender"
        default-request-channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" 
    />

    <int-ip:udp-outbound-channel-adapter id="metoo" channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" port="11111" host="localhost"/>

public interface Sender {
    public void sendMessage(String message);
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/new_tutorial.xml");
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();

        Sender sender = (Sender) context.getBean("sender");
        sender.sendMessage("123");
    }
}
```

The `Sender` interface is the entrance point (gateway) into the Spring Integration API. Once one method on this gateway is called, the message is put on channel and via outbound channel adapter is sent.

Comment: I have make code like you for Sender but it shows an error : `NoSuchMethodException`..

Comment: Which method from which class does throw this error? Also, which method does it say it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing consuming from `quakeinfotrigger` - you have two polled inbound adapters and the UDP inbound adapters that all produce messages and send them to that channel, but you need something to actually do something with the messages.